# python class output at the interpreter

Tags: python, class, output

I have the following python class:

```
class uf_node:
    def __init__(self, Vertex):
        self.vertex = Vertex
        self.rep = Vertex

    def set_rep(self, Rep):
        self.rep = Rep
```

Now, at the interpreter I do the following:

```
>>> from uf_node import *
>>> u = uf_node('a')
>>> u
<uf_node.uf_node instance at 0x7f56069ca758>
```

Can one get better output, perhaps creating something like a 'toString()' function that would automatically be called when you try to print the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REPL invokes [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) function of your class. So, you can override [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and `__repr__` functions like this

```
class uf_node:
    def __init__(self, Vertex):
        self.vertex = Vertex
        self.rep = Vertex

    def set_rep(self, Rep):
        self.rep = Rep

    def __str__(self):
        return "Rep: {}, Vertex: {}".format(self.rep, self.vertex)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Rep: {}, Vertex: {}".format(self.rep, self.vertex)
```

With this change,

```
>>> u = uf_node('a')
>>> u
Rep: a, Vertex: a
>>>
```

**Note:** You can read more about the differences between `__str__` and `__repr__` in this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the **str** or **repr** class methods.

`__str__` handles the conversion to a string while `__repr__` is the string representation of your class you could use if your wanted to instanciate it again. `__repr__` is supposed to return a valid Python expression. Both methods return a string. You usually call these methods with the string constructor `str()` (the str class will call the `__str__` method) or the `repr()` function.

```
class uf_node(object):
    def __init__(self, Vertex):
        self.vertex = Vertex
        self.rep = Vertex

    def set_rep(self, Rep):
        self.rep = Rep

    def __str__(self):
        '''Used for string conversion'''
        return 'This node uses vertex %s' % self.vertex

    def __repr__(self):
        '''Used for string representation'''
        return 'uf_node(%s)' % repr(self.vertex)

v = uf_node('a')
print str(v) # -> 'This node used vertex a'
print repr(v) # -> "uf_node('a')
```

Check the doc here, it is well explained : https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html